# Implement fibonacci in Clojure using map/reduce

Tags: clojure, fibonacci, reduce

Is it possible to implement the fibonacci series in Clojure efficiently using `reduce`? What would the "accumulator" contain?

I imagine that it will have to be lazy. It's obvious how to do it using recursion or loop/recur.

Comment: BTW, what prompted this question was reading "Land of Lisp" by Conrad Barski, MD. In his chapter on macros, he cautions against their overuse and offers alternatives using `map` and `reduce`. Got me thinking...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a pair of successive fibonacci values as the accumulator, as follows:

```
(reduce 
  (fn [[a b] _] [b (+ a b)])  ; function to calculate the next pair of values
  [0 1]                       ; initial pair of fibonnaci numbers
  (range 10))                 ; a seq to specify how many iterations you want

=> [55 89]
```

This is not particularly efficient due to the creation of lots of intermediate pairs and use of the superfluous range sequence to drive the right number of iterations, but it is O(n) from an algorithmic perspective (i.e. the same as the efficient iterative solution, and much better than the naive recursive one).

Comment: Might it help if you used memoize?

Comment: @Ralph - not really in this case since the function is getting called with different values every time. Memoise would of course help a lot if you used a recursive implementation....

Comment: Not bad! I did `(time (fib 10000))` using your implementation and it executes in 71 msec (MacBook Pro 2.66 GHz i7).

Comment: Don't worry about the creation of pairs, it's negligible compared to the addition of `BigInteger`s. On my machine using loop and recur is 20ms faster for `(fib 100000)`, with a total runtime of ca 700ms.

Comment: And because the cost of addition of BigIntegers is a function of their size, the algorithm is probably really more like O(n*n). : http://lee-phillips.org/lispmath/

Comment: @mikera how can I return the entire list of fibonacci values?

Comment: @Ralph How can we incorporate memoize to get the full list?

Answer (score 5):

Not using map/reduce, but iterate can avoid recursion too.

```
(defn iter [[x y]]
  (vector y (+ x y)))

(nth (iterate iter [0 1]) 10000)
```

This takes 21ms on an Intel 2.4 Ghz

On the same machine, reduce takes 61msec. Not sure why iterate is faster.

```
   (time (reduce 
     (fn [[a b] _] [b (+ a b)])  ; function to calculate the next pair of values
     [0 1]                       ; initial pair of fibonnaci numbers
     (range 10000)))
```