# In clojure, how to build lazy sequence using iterate function

Tags: clojure

The clojure [document](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/iterate) gives the following examples:

```
(take 10 (iterate (partial + 2) 0))

(def powers-of-two (iterate (partial * 2) 1))
(take 10 powers-of-two)

(def fib (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [1 1])))
(take 10 fib)
```

Anyone can explain the syntax of clojure's iterate function in more detail? I am very confused with all the usage. Why two brackets are there in (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)])?

Another example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537221/323941):

```
(defn iter [[x y]]
  (vector y (+ x y)))

(nth (iterate iter [0 1]) 10000)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`iterate` takes a function `f` and an initial value `x` and produces a lazy sequence. The first element in the seq is `x`. Each subsequent element is computed by calling `f` with the previous element.

**Example 1:**

```
(iterate (partial + 2) 0)
```

This generates a sequence, starting at 0, where each element is the previous element with 2 added to it. I.e.:

```
0
(+ 2 0) ; => 2
(+ 2 2) ; => 4
(+ 2 4) ; => 6
; etc
```

Each element in the seq is passed to `(partial + 2)` when generating the following element.

**Example 2:**

```
(iterate (partial * 2) 1)
```

This generates a sequence, starting at 1, where each element is the previous element multiplied by 2. I.e.:

```
1
(* 2 1) ; => 2
(* 2 2) ; => 4
(* 2 4) ; => 8
(* 2 8) ; => 16
; etc
```

Again, you can see how each element feeds into the generation of the next one.

**Example 3:**

```
(iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [1 1])
```

Firstly, `(fn [[a b]] ...)` is a way to [destructure](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5Bbindings%2a%20%5D%20exprs%2a%29) a value into parts. In this case, the function accepts a two-element vector and unpacks it into the local variables `a` and `b`.

The function returns a two-element vector containing `b` and the sum of `a` and `b` (i.e. the second value in the previous pair and the sum of both values in the previous pair).

With this in mind, this `iterate` call generates:

```
[1 1]
[1 (+ 1 1)] ; => [1 2]
[2 (+ 1 2)] ; => [2 3]
[3 (+ 2 3)] ; => [3 5]
[5 (+ 3 5)] ; => [5 8]
; etc
```

Then `(map first ...)` grabs the first value in each pair, which gives you your Fibonacci sequence.